# php require file

Tags: php, require

I have trouble for requiring a file:

```
$path_requires = "/var/www/vhosts/website.com/v3" ;

require("$path_requires/vars.inc.php") ;
```

The error is:

> /var/www/vhosts/website.com/portraits Fatal error: require(): Failed
>   opening required '/var/www/vhosts/website.com/v3/vars.inc.php'

If i do from a terminal:

```
cat /var/www/vhosts/website.com/v3/vars.inc.php
```

I checked the permissions on the directory. website.com. it's:

> drwxr-xr-x 17 apache  psaserv 4096 Oct 18 03:32 v3

I changed the permissions to that directory with no success.

Does anyone know what is going on. Why I can't require this php file ?

Comment: Can you show the permissions on the v3 folder and on the .inc.php file ?

Comment: It's normal that your path require is /var/www/vhosts/website.com/v3 and in your console you ask /var/www/vhosts/bookonlive.com/v3 ?

Comment: The error message looks in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/, and you cat from /var/www/vhosts/bookonlive.com/ which is not the same folder.

Comment: I think he's just using website.com as an example folks.

Comment: v3 folder:
drwxr-xr-x 17 apache  psaserv 4096 Oct 18 03:32 v3

for the permissions on the file. i don't know. i can't access to the server anymore. connection timeout!

Comment: permissions for the file vars.inc.php:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 vincent psaserv     4889 Aug 26 03:21 vars.inc.php`

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it's looking for the /var/www/vhosts folder inside your actual hosting and quite obviously not finding it. Try:

```
$path_requires = "/v3" ;

require("$path_requires/vars.inc.php") ;
```

Comment: I have the same error. But there are 2 sub-domains:
sub1.mysite.com
sub2.mysite.com
I have to be able to require a file from one sub1 when the script executed on sub2. That's why I try to require the file from the root system /__/__/etc...

Comment: Try adding one level up then, the website.com I am pretty sure what's happening is since it's in a browser it's getting confused by the directory structure. Your site externally (in a browser) is not seeing the internal structure of your web host.

Answer (score 0):

Check using this

```
$path_requires = "https://www.website.com/v3" ; (base url)

require("$path_requires/vars.inc.php") ;
```

Comment: same error.and yet the url is correct! I can access to:
http://v3.mysite.com/vars.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo() result:

```
open_basedir    /var/www/vhosts/website.com/portraits/:/tmp/    no value
```

The /etc/php.ini:

```
;open_basedir =
```

How to change the local value ? If I change /etc/php.ini the local value have the upper hand.

/website.com/portraits/
portraits is the directory of the sub-domain portraits.website.com